# In App Inventor can I lay text box or labels over a Canvas

Tags: android, app-inventor

I am making an app that kind of calculates a triangle. On screen 1 the user inputs variables via text boxes. The calcs are done on on screen 1. Also the variables are passed to Screen 2 via Tiny DB to graphically draw the "triangle" on a canvas.
I want to put labels over the canvas to show data that will move with the position of the triangle when it gets redrawn. How can i Achieve this?
Thanks

James

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `labels` inside the `canvas`, but you can use the `DrawText` method or `DrawTextAtAngle` method to write some text onto the `canvas` instead, see also the [documentation](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/components/animation.html#Canvas).

> DrawText(text text, number x, number y)
> Draws the specified text relative to the specified coordinates using the values of the FontSize and TextAlignment properties.
>
> DrawTextAtAngle(text text, number x, number y, number angle)
> Draws the specified text starting at the specified coordinates at the specified angle using the values of the FontSize and TextAlignment
> properties.